# Yii: Called Mail() without being connected

Tags: php, email, yii, phpmailer

I am trying to send email in `Yii` using `PHPMailer`. I am working on a live server. Here is my Configuration for email in `Yii's` `main.php`:

```
'Smtpmail' => array(
            'class' => 'application.extensions.smtpmail.PHPMailer',
            'Mailer' => 'smtp',
            'SMTPAuth' => true,
        ),
```

Here is the error I get:

> The following From address failed: noreply@mywebsite.com : Called
>   Mail() without being connected

Here is my controller Code:

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->From = Yii::app()->params['adminEmail'];
$mail->FromName = empty($_POST['EmailForm']["from_name"]) 
Yii::app()->params['emailFrom'] : $_POST['EmailForm']["from_name"];
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = nl2br($message) . $mail->Body;
$mail->AddAddress($to);
$mail->AddCC($cc);

if (!$mail->Send()) {
    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error', $mail->ErrorInfo);
    $this->redirect(array('update', 'id' => $id));
} 
else {
      Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', "Email sent successfully!");
      $this->redirect(array('update', 'id' => $id));
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're enabling auth but not providing an id or password, which doesn't seem likely to work. You're also setting the submitter's address as the from address, which is also likely to fail as it's a forgery that will fail SPF checks. Set your own address as the from address and put the submitter in a reply-to.

Beyond that, enable debug output (`SMTPDebug = 2` in PHPMailer - I'm not sure how you set that from Yii) so you can see the SMTP conversation.